# Where are launchd LaunchEvents dictionaries / keys documented

Tags: macos, launchd, macos-mojave

According to the launchd.plist man page, LaunchEvents takes a "dictionary of dictionaries of dictionaries", and it lists com.apple.iokit.matching as an example of a top level dictionary. I *suspect* what I'm looking for will be in com.apple.notifyd.matching. But, I can't find anywhere a list of valid sub-keys. The Apple developer information on daemonification and agents (https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/Introduction.html#/) seems not to have it ... and also seems to be a couple of years old, so I'm wondering if I'm even barking up the right tree.

There's some good, basic information at http://www.launchd.info, and TechnoGeeks provides a more comprehensive dive, including some undocumented stuff at http://technologeeks.com/docs/launchd.pdf ...

But, does anyone know where I can find documentation on native MacOS (preferably Mojave) supported dictionaries / keys for LaunchEvents?

Comment: I'm really curious about this as well, and have been investigating. These seem to come from plugins which exist in /System/Library/UserEventPlugins — and there are quite a few. But there are no docs.